# Levi-Civita and Matrix Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I have the following relations:

$$\epsilon_{lmn}\det{A} = \epsilon_{ijk}a_{li}a_{mj}a_{nk} $$
and
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\det{A} = \epsilon_{lmn}a_{li}a_{mj}a_{nk} $$

I can see from the logic why these statements are true as they represent all the possible combinations of solutions where the following is true:
$$\det{A} = \epsilon_{ijk}a_{li}a_{mj}a_{nk} $$
for all allowed combinations of $l$, $m$ and $n$.

What I can't do is successfully prove this mathematically nor can I find a proof. Can anyone show me a convincing proof for the above?

Thanks to the comments I have multiplied both sides of the following equation by $\epsilon_{lmn}$

$$\det{A} = \epsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3k}$$

to obtain,

$$\epsilon_{lmn}\det{A} = a_{1l}a_{2m}a_{3n} + a_{1m}a_{2n}a_{3l} + a_{1m}a_{2l}a_{3n} - a_{1l}a_{2n}a_{3m} - a_{1m}a_{2l}a_{3n} - a_{1n}a_{2m}a_{3l}$$

it is clear that the even permutations of $_{123}$ are positive and the odd permutations of $_{lmn}$ are negative.

However, I am unsure of the mathematical step (if any) I should take to represent it in this form:
 $$\epsilon_{ijk}a_{li}a_{mj}a_{nk}$$

Comment: A place to start might be to multiply each side by $\epsilon_{lmn}$ and note that: $\epsilon_{lmn}\epsilon_{ijk} = \delta_{il}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn} + \delta_{im}\delta_{jn}\delta_{kl} +\delta_{in}\delta_{jl}\delta_{km} - \delta_{il}\delta_{jn}\delta_{km} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}\delta_{kn} -\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl} $.

Comment: thanks I will go that a go

Comment: @kmeis I expanded out and applied the kronecker-deltas. It's now obvious to me why it simplifies out but still I am unsure how to prove it mathematically

Comment: I apologize for such a late response, but one property of kronecker delta is if $\delta_{ij}A_{im} = A_{jm} $. It provides a chanhe of indices